# Cannot get listen gem to work

Tags: ruby

I am simply trying to get the [listen gem](https://github.com/guard/listen) to work, and just tried the basic example in [the documentation](https://github.com/guard/listen#usage).

Here is what I just tried, with some info about my installation. I am running on CentOS.

```
$ uname -a
Linux www14405ue.sakura.ne.jp 2.6.32-279.2.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jul 20 01:55:29 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-linux]
$ gem install listen
....
6 gems installed
$ gem list listen

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

listen (2.0.1)
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
$ mkdir bar
$ vim listen.rb
$ cat listen.rb
require 'listen'
listener = Listen.to('bar') do |modified, added, removed|
  puts "modified absolute path: #{modified}"
  puts "added absolute path: #{added}"
  puts "removed absolute path: #{removed}"
end
listener.start # not blocking
sleep
$ ruby listen.rb
$ echo "baz" > bar/baz   # from the same directory in another terminal
$ echo "qux" >> bar/baz  # a moment later 
$ rm bar/baz             # again a moment later
```

I would have expected some output for the two `echo` and the `rm` but I did not get anything. I tried to change the listen path from `bar` to `./bar` but this did not help either.

What am I missing here?

Comment: works for me.  mkdir bar; ./listen-example.rb& ; touch bar/one; modified absolute path: ["/home/wc3829/me/code/bar/one"]
added absolute path: ["/home/wc3829/me/code/bar/one"]
removed absolute path: []

Comment: chmod +x listen.rb; ruby listen.rb &

Comment: Mm, I get absolutely no output. Changing the permissions on listen.rb did not help either.
I wonder if that could have anything to do with rvm, though I could hardly see why.

Comment: I'm running fedora.  I notice you didn't run in background '&', and didn't give local path ./listen.rb -- try, ./listen.rb &

Comment: I just tried to run it in background but that did not seem to help.
What version of Ruby/listen gem are you using by the way?

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3, listen 2.0.1

Comment: I just tried with exactly the same versions and still no success. I really wonder what am I doing wrong.
Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38823/discussion-between-chuckcottrill-and-daniel-perez)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really understand why, but it seems that the problem was I was working under a `~/tmp` directory. After changing the working directory, everything started working properly. I am not really sure why, but anyway that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. it should be full path to directory
2. it must be real file system  - not working with tmpfs